Why do Innovus commands have two forms? For example floorPlan and init_design
Why do Innovus commands have two forms? For example floorPlan and init_design
like below
the first form:

the second form:

Is it because they come from different sources? Or is part of it a tcl command?
I just started learning Innovus and don’t have a detailed understanding of these commands.
If anyone can answer this for me, I would be grateful
